# Elementary Geometry Proof + parallelograms

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry

[image]

i)

$AX = CY$ (Given)

$AD = BC$ (Opposite sides of a ||gram)

$DX = YB$ (Equal Base Angle of an Isosceles) (since if 2 sides or 2 angles are equal the third is going to be the same..)

Therefore ADX and CBY are congruent by the rule SSS (Side, Side, Side)

ii) I can't do this one, if someone can know how show me pls.

Comment: What do you know about the length and measure of opposite sides and angles in a parallelogram?

Comment: they are equal.

Comment: Indeed. So you can deduce that AD = AX hence ADX is isosceles. Now use the equal angles and that's it.

Answer (score 1):

$ADX$ congruent to $CBY\ \Rightarrow\ \widehat{YCB}=\widehat{DAX}$
On the other hand in parallelogram we have: $\widehat{DAB}=\widehat{BCD}\ $ so we conclude that: $\widehat{YAX}=\widehat{YCX}$
$\widehat{AXD}=\widehat{BYC}\ \Rightarrow\ \widehat{AXC}=\widehat{AYC}\ \Rightarrow\ AYCX$ is a parallelogram.